# nodejs: fs.access is undefined

Tags: node.js, fs

I am using nodejs/express to develop a simple RESTful API.
Yesterday I could make calls to the `fs.access` method (used to check the existence of a file/folder). I can't today. Even if I use the REPL on the terminal it says `fs.access` is undefined. This is the output:

```
> var fs = require('fs');
undefined
> fs.access
undefined
> fs.exists
[Function]
```

`nodejs --version` gives me this version, which is the latest available from Ubuntu's repositories: `v0.10.25`

I know there is the `fs.exists` method, but as [per documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) it has been deprecated.

How can I solve?

Thank you,
Umar

Comment: Node.js is way, way beyond v.0.10.25.

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed. Yesterday everything was working fine, same distro, same configuration. Also, the Ubuntu package repository (for Ubuntu 15.10) shows 0.10.25 as the latest version available. Any ideas?

Comment: v5.0.0 is here: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.0.0/.  I have no idea why your environment changed.

Comment: Maybe you were using an fs extension that provides this method?

Comment: I solved by installing nodejs using the NodeSource repository: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js version 0.10.25 is not the latest and according to it's [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.25/api/fs.html) a function named access is indeed not present in the file system api.

According to the [official website](http://nodejs.org), the latest LTS version is 4.2.6 and the latest stable one is 5.5.0. I've just checked and everything works as excepted on my computer using a recent version of Node.js.

If you're having trouble installing a more recent version of Node through your distribution's channels, you might want to consider using a third party package manager like [Linuxbrew](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/linuxbrew) that installs stuff into your home directory, independent of the OS you're using.

Comment: Thank you, I solved by installing nodejs using the NodeSource repository: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions